# C# namespace search

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm new to c# and I'm always Googling to find namespaces.  Is there a better way, a namespace search page or something like that?

Thanks

Comment: Er, what are you trying to find namespaces for? You can browse the standard library on MSDN, but I usually just do a web search for what I want and it's the first hit or so.

Comment: Do you mean namespace for a .NET class? The help file should tell you that.  For third-party libraries, I'd expect the library's documentation would say.  I'm not sure I understand the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for the .NET Class Library: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx

Comment: Or are you looking for third-party .NET Assemblies?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using visual studio (express) you can simply use the help (either locally, or it will redirect you to the msdn website).

On the other hand I've often found that if a site offers exactly the information you look for, it's often easier to use google than the sites build in search functions :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's a [nice list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229335.aspx) of all namespaces in the .NET libraries on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/buy/index.jsp) plugin

If you're a student or developing open source projects, it's free

Answer (score 1):

Are you referring to finding the right DLL for a given namespace?  Some namespaces are spread amongst several DLLs.  Each class page on MSDN will list which DLL that class is in.  E.G. The [DataContractAttribute class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx) is in the System.Runtime.Serialization.dll.